# How to use $search $text in Doctrine Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I build the native mongo db query below with Doctrine query builder?

```
db.Product.find({
$text: {$search: 'CaSe InSEnsitive'}, 
title: {$regex:/^CaSe InSEnsitive$/i} 
});
```

This query will speed up the case insensitive search by using the text search index!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$expr = $query->expr()->operator('$text', array(
                '$search'   => $param['title'],
                '$language' => 'en', // or one of those other languages
            ));

$query->field(null)->equals($expr->getQuery());
```